# Dock icons changing sometimes

Tags: dock, icon

I noticed that some app icons changing sometimes with same blank like icon. Right now Sublime Text icon changed. Couple days ago it was happened on Safari. How can I prevent this? What will can cause this?

[image: Sublime Text dock icon changed]

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to reset and restart the Dock. Note you will need to re-add any non-default icons (i.e. apps) that you've added to the Dock - so you may want to take a screenshot of your Dock as a reminder of what you had there. (Or start afresh and only add things as you actually use them).

To reset and restart the Dock, follow these steps:

- Go to Finder
- Press and hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key down
- Now go to the Go menu
- Select the Library option to open the User's *Library* folder. You can let go of the <kbd>option</kbd> key now.
- Go to the Preferences folder (i.e. within the Library folder)
- Find and move the **com.apple.dock.plist** file to the Trash
- Now open Terminal (usually located in Applications > Utilities)
- Enter this command `killall -KILL Dock`
- Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

This should resolve the issue. As mentioned previously, you will need to re-add non-default apps back to the Dock.